# Load the next 10 record via Ajax Search Box using PHP MySQL and JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

I have see the example about search box using JQuery and mysql, But the view more function no work. how to improve the program. When i click the view more i can see the next 10 record. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#keywords").keyup(function()
  {
    var kw = $("#keywords").val();
    if(kw != '')  
     {
      $.ajax
      ({
         type: "POST",
         url: "search.php",
         data: "kw="+ kw,
         success: function(option)
         {
           $("#results").html(option);
         }
      });
     }
     else
     {
       $("#results").html("");
     }
    return false;
  });

   $(".overlay").click(function()
   {
     $(".overlay").css('display','none');
     $("#results").css('display','none');
   });
   $("#keywords").focus(function()
   {
     $(".overlay").css('display','block');
     $("#results").css('display','block');
   });
});
</script>



<div id="inputbox">
    <input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" value="" placeholder="Type Your Query..."/>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

we extract the value of that key and send it to the search.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//file which contains the database details.
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['kw']) && $_POST['kw'] != '')
{
  $kws = $_POST['kw'];
  $kws = mysql_real_escape_string($kws); 
  $query = "select * from wp_posts where post_name like '%".$kws."%' and (post_type='post' and post_status='publish') limit 10" ;
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
  $i = 0;

  if($count > 0)
  {
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
      echo "<a href='$row[guid]'><li>";
      echo "<div id='rest'>";
      echo $row['post_name'];
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<div id='auth_dat'>".$row['post_date']."</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div></li></a>";
      $i++;
      if($i == 5) break;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    if($count > 5)
    {
      echo "<div id='view_more'><a href='#'>View more results</a></div>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<div id='no_result'>No result found !</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

press the view more result will not show more result.

Comment: You do have form tags, *right*?

Comment: you mean id='view_more'?

Comment: sorry~ not understand~

Comment: Inputs need to be wrapped in form tags.

Comment: you mean  here--> 
<input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" value="" placeholder="Type Your Query..."/>
  </div>

Comment: i have no problem to search the result, but the view more result function is not work.

Comment: this can help http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/loading-more-results-from-database

Comment: This difficult use in my program :(

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to bring next 10 with ajax ? 
This situation behaves as a pagination, 
You have to store the current click count in javascript . Wİthout clicking more button, the variable of clickCount is 0, when you click more ,then your variable clickCount=1  ,
while sending ajax , send clickCount to the php.

```
 $.ajax
  ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "search.php",
     data: "kw="+ kw+"&clickCount="+clickCount,
     success: function(option)
     {
       $("#results").html(option);
     }
  });
```

You can query with limit&offset (clickCount )*10, itemCountForEachMoreClick = limit 0,10
when click more
limit 10,10
when click one more
limit 20,10. Do not forget to reset clickCount on keyPress !

php Side

```
 $count = isset($_REQUEST["clickCount"])? $_REQUEST["clickCount"]:0;
$limitAndOffset = $count*10.",10";    
$query = "select * from wp_posts where post_name like '%".$kws."%' 
    and (post_type='post' and post_status='publish') limit ".$limitAndOffset  ;
```